# How to get the Cordova www root url using javascript?

Tags: cordova

What is the root url for cordova www folder like
`///storage/0/emulated/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova is part of the packaging process; it doesn't actually reside within the output of your project, but rather on your build environment. As such, you cannot know the Cordova root using JavaScript.

You'd typically install Cordova with NPM using `npm install -g cordova`, and if you're installing Cordova globally as a NodeJS package, it would end up in your `%AppData%` by default, specifically in `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova` (which is the same as `%AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova`).